# P2P Frameworks (for a social network project)

Tags: social-networking, p2p

For my license degree (I'm a CS student) I have to build a P2P Social Network. I've done some research over the internet but I couldn't find clear info about how I could achieve this or any good resources related to this type of project.

That's why I wanted to ask if you know some really good resources about P2P Social Network Frameworks which I should use; your take regarding this subject!

Thanks!

Comment: P2P Social-Network is a very vague term. Can you please describe a little what you have in mind??? You want a web-based system? it would be great if you can give some example features so that people can suggest solutions accordingly.

Comment: What I want: the same functionalities like Facebook (friends, photo sharing, posts, etc) but without a central server where all the data is kept - just a large network where every users acts like a client and like a server!

Comment: All the informations are distributed - there are no central servers where the data is kept. The users have complete control over their data!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Newebe a P2P social network that fits well with your description. It could give you some ideas.

http://newebe.org/